# Sidebar generated by angular material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, sidebar

hello so i generated a sidebar from angular material but it won't work this is the code i tried a lot of things but it won't work  help please, this is my first time working with angular material so i'm not quite good with it

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="">Demande de crédit</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="">Etude de crédit</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Tableau d'amortissement</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Echéancier de rembourssement</a>
      <span class="slide">
      
      </span>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      
      <span>APP</span>
   
    </mat-toolbar>
    <app-form class="form"></app-form>
 
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and this is stacktrace:

```
ROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3203:40)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3261:12)
    at NodeInjector.get (core.mjs:3526:16)
    at OutletInjector.get (router.mjs:2691:28)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12090:37)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3216:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3261:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10057:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DefaultValueAccessor_Factory [as factory] (forms.mjs:66:110)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3446:44)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1168:17)
    at zone.js:1281:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at core.mjs:23892:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23892:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24193:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

Comment: Your mat sidebar setup works fine, you error stacktrace just tells you that you are ending up in some sort of recursive loop. [Here is a mock](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nes2yp?file=src/app/sidenav-overview-example.ts) of your code running with the sidebar working. The error might be somewhere else in your code. Try attaching a debugger in your constructor, and see where it hangs.